# How do you change URI and display results - using Algolia

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algolia

I would like to change the hit uri for particular categories ("travel" and "food"). This is my code so far. I can get results to be displayed though and I have and warning (Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render). I have never used Algolia before so I am stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import { Link } from "gatsby"
import { default as React } from "react"
import {
  connectStateResults,
  Highlight,
  Hits,
  Index,
  Snippet,
  PoweredBy,
} from "react-instantsearch-dom"

const HitCount = connectStateResults(({ searchResults }) => {
  const hitCount = searchResults && searchResults.nbHits
  return hitCount > 0 ? (
    <div className="HitCount">
      {hitCount} result{hitCount !== 1 ? `s` : ``}
    </div>
  ) : null
})

const regex = new RegExp(/\btravel\b/)

const PageHit =
  clickHandler =>
  ({ hit }) =>
    (
      <div>
        {hit.uri.match(regex) ? (
          <div>
            <Link
              to={`${hit.uri}`.replace(
                "travel",
                `travels/${hit.travelFields.category
                  .replace(/\s+/g, "-")
                  .toLowerCase()}`
              )}
              onClick={clickHandler}
            >
              <h4 className="text-base leading-tight font-extralight">
                <Highlight attribute="title" hit={hit} tagName="mark" />
              </h4>
            </Link>
            <Snippet attribute="excerpt" hit={hit} tagName="mark" />
          </div>
        ) : hit.uri.match("food") ? (
          <div>
            <Link
              to={`${hit.uri}`.replace(
                "food",
                `foods/${hit.cfeFoods.category.toLowerCase()}`
              )}
              onClick={clickHandler}
            >
              <h4 className="text-base leading-tight font-extralight">
                <Highlight attribute="title" hit={hit} tagName="mark" />
              </h4>
            </Link>
            <Snippet attribute="excerpt" hit={hit} tagName="mark" />
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div>
            <Link to={`${hit.uri}`} onClick={clickHandler}>
              <h4 className="text-base leading-tight font-extralight">
                <Highlight attribute="title" hit={hit} tagName="mark" />
              </h4>
            </Link>
            <Snippet attribute="excerpt" hit={hit} tagName="mark" />
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    )

const HitsInIndex = ({ index }) => (
  <Index indexName={index.name}>
    <HitCount />
    <Hits className="Hits" hitComponent={PageHit} />
  </Index>
)

const SearchResult = ({ indices, className }) => (
  <div className={className}>
    {indices.map(index => (
      <HitsInIndex index={index} key={index.name} />
    ))}
    <PoweredBy />
  </div>
)

export default SearchResult
```

Answer (score 0):

`clickHandler` is not passed anywhere, but if you have access to it in the scope of SearchResult, you can change the code to:

```
import { Link } from 'gatsby';
import { default as React } from 'react';
import {
  connectStateResults,
  Highlight,
  Hits,
  Index,
  Snippet,
  PoweredBy,
} from 'react-instantsearch-dom';

const HitCount = connectStateResults(({ searchResults }) => {
  const hitCount = searchResults && searchResults.nbHits;
  return hitCount > 0 ? (
    <div className="HitCount">
      {hitCount} result{hitCount !== 1 ? `s` : ``}
    </div>
  ) : null;
});

const regex = new RegExp(/\btravel\b/);

const createPageHit =
  (clickHandler) =>
  ({ hit }) =>
    (
      <div>
        {hit.uri.match(regex) ? (
          <div>
            <Link
              to={`${hit.uri}`.replace(
                'travel',
                `travels/${hit.travelFields.category
                  .replace(/\s+/g, '-')
                  .toLowerCase()}`
              )}
              onClick={clickHandler}
            >
              <h4 className="text-base leading-tight font-extralight">
                <Highlight attribute="title" hit={hit} tagName="mark" />
              </h4>
            </Link>
            <Snippet attribute="excerpt" hit={hit} tagName="mark" />
          </div>
        ) : hit.uri.match('food') ? (
          <div>
            <Link
              to={`${hit.uri}`.replace(
                'food',
                `foods/${hit.cfeFoods.category.toLowerCase()}`
              )}
              onClick={clickHandler}
            >
              <h4 className="text-base leading-tight font-extralight">
                <Highlight attribute="title" hit={hit} tagName="mark" />
              </h4>
            </Link>
            <Snippet attribute="excerpt" hit={hit} tagName="mark" />
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div>
            <Link to={`${hit.uri}`} onClick={clickHandler}>
              <h4 className="text-base leading-tight font-extralight">
                <Highlight attribute="title" hit={hit} tagName="mark" />
              </h4>
            </Link>
            <Snippet attribute="excerpt" hit={hit} tagName="mark" />
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );

const HitsInIndex = ({ index, clickHandler }) => (
  <Index indexName={index.name}>
    <HitCount />
    <Hits className="Hits" hitComponent={createPageHit(clickHandler)} />
  </Index>
);

const SearchResult = ({ indices, className }) => {
  return (
    <div className={className}>
      {indices.map((index) => (
        <HitsInIndex
          key={index.name}
          index={index}
          clickHandler={(event) => {
            console.log('do something with', event);
          }}
        />
      ))}
      <PoweredBy />
    </div>
  );
};

export default SearchResult;
```

Note how `PageHit` in your question is not a React component, but a function returning a React component, so it would need to be called first.

There's other ways, like context to pass the clickHandler lower too.

Answer (score 0):

Injecting the `clickHandler =>` into your PageHit renderer is what's causing the confusion. This should work without that piece.

```
const PageHit =
  ({ hit }) =>
    (
      <div>
        {hit.uri.match(regex) ? (
          <div>
            <Link
              to={`${hit.uri}`.replace(
                "travel",
                `travels/${hit.travelFields.category
                  .replace(/\s+/g, "-")
                  .toLowerCase()}`
              )}
              onClick={clickHandler}
            >
              <h4 className="text-base leading-tight font-extralight">
                <Highlight attribute="title" hit={hit} tagName="mark" />
              </h4>
            </Link>
            <Snippet attribute="excerpt" hit={hit} tagName="mark" />
          </div>
        ) : hit.uri.match("food") ? (
          <div>
            <Link
              to={`${hit.uri}`.replace(
                "food",
                `foods/${hit.cfeFoods.category.toLowerCase()}`
              )}
              onClick={clickHandler}
            >
              <h4 className="text-base leading-tight font-extralight">
                <Highlight attribute="title" hit={hit} tagName="mark" />
              </h4>
            </Link>
            <Snippet attribute="excerpt" hit={hit} tagName="mark" />
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div>
            <Link to={`${hit.uri}`} onClick={clickHandler}>
              <h4 className="text-base leading-tight font-extralight">
                <Highlight attribute="title" hit={hit} tagName="mark" />
              </h4>
            </Link>
            <Snippet attribute="excerpt" hit={hit} tagName="mark" />
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    )
```

I'm having trouble understanding the intent of `clickHandler =>` in that context?